# R svg or RdevSVG boxplots fail to open in both Illustrator and Inkscape

Tags: r, svg, inkscape

I am exporting simple boxplots using R and as these figures should be used for publication I export them as svg using both R svg() and RdevSVG() drivers.

```
svg ( "svg.svg")
boxplot(list, main="Title",outline=FALSE,las=2, cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, lwd=2, cex.lab=2, ylim=c(-1.72413913131201, 2.26778683805536) )
dev.off()

devSVG( "devSVG.svg" )
boxplot(list, main="Title",outline=FALSE,las=2, cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, lwd=2, cex.lab=2, ylim=c(-1.72413913131201, 2.26778683805536) )
dev.off()
```

File svg.svg renders OK in Inkscape and can be used together with image magick. Transfering it to a colaborators MAC and opening it with illustrator renders the file useless as the text totally blocks all of the figure.

File devSVG.svg is absolutely unusable as the text is not even readable using inkscape.

I hope you can help me, but I will also post my solution when I found it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found an answer and want to document it here ;-)

The only way to get usable svg files for both inkscape and illustrator seams to be:

(1) R export as pdf using

```
pdf ( "pdf.pdf")
boxplot(list, main="Title",outline=FALSE,las=2, cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, lwd=2, cex.lab=2, ylim=c(-1.72413913131201, 2.26778683805536) )
dev.off()
```

(2) use inkscape to rescale the canvas

```
File -> document properties -> Resize page to drawing or selection
```

(3) save file as svg

This SVG file looks OK using both inkscape and illustrator.

Hope this post saves time later on...

Comment: So you are creating a vector file from a raster file? How about `CairoSVG`? (if you have capability).

Comment: Sorry misspelled! PNG is wrong - I exported as PDF...

PDF to my knowledge is also vector format.
CairoSVG was unknown to me - thank you.
Installed - tested - failed :-(
The results are the same as for the svg driver alone. At least on my Fedora20 system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to size your `dev` or try the `editSVG` function from `RSvgDevice`.

```
library(RSvgDevice)
editSVG(boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray"))
```

To size `svg` or `devSVG`, just provide an explicit `height` and `width`.  Using your example.

```
svg("svg.svg", height = 12, width = 16)

boxplot(
  list, main="Title",outline=FALSE,las=2,
  cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, lwd=2, cex.lab=2,
  ylim=c(-1.72413913131201, 2.26778683805536)
)
```